# How to hide a path on a rectangle

Tags: adobe-illustrator

With a rectangle shape I'd like to remove/hide one side of the rectangle so it looks like one side is open. I've seen online where the focus is on removing/cutting/deleting the stroke but it leaves me to think that then I can't fill the shape as it will have open paths. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think you need a [Clipping mask](https://helpx.adobe.com/fi/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html). Basically, draw a new shape to use as the clipping mask on top of your existing object(s), select all layers and make a clipping mask.

Comment: Thanks. But if I think a little ahead let's say I had a segment of the path deleted in a circle. Would the fill still extend to look like the circle or will it be a flat line that invisibly joins one point to the near other point?

Comment: @Dan - see update to my answer

Comment: Right... If you want to keep the circle fill untouched, but cut up the stroke, you're going to need 2 objects. So likely you'd want to to duplicate the object and make it so one copy has just the stroke and the other has the fill  (like in Billy's second example). And it then doesn't really matter whether or not you use a clipping mask or path finder or whatever else to snip the stroke into little tiny pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select a segment with the Direct Selection tool <kbd>A</kbd>, then hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>. Open paths can still have a fill attribute.

Example

[image]

For a circle or a more complex shape, another approach would be needed if you want to retain a fill in the shape of the original.

1. Create a circle with a fill and no stroke
2. Copy and Paste in Place
3. Set a stroke, and no fill
4. Delete one segment of the circle

Example

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant. Many thanks for this.